# Basis independent proof that $K[X]/p_{_l}\cong K(l)$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

For an algebraic field extension $[L:K]$ with $l\in L$ and $p_{_l}\in K[X]$ the minimal polynomial of $l$, is there a basis independent proof that $K[X]/p_{_l}\cong K(l)$?

I know a proof that uses $\{x_i+(p_{_l})\}_{i<deg(p_{_l})}$ as a basis for $K[X]/p_{_l}$ and $\{l^i\}_{i<deg(p_{_l})}$ as a basis for $K(l)$, but is there a standard basis free proof? (perhaps using that both fields coequalize the same two arrows in the category of fields?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is the Kernel of the canonical ring homomorphism
$$K[X] \to K(l),$$
$$X \mapsto l?$$

It would also be instructive to consider what happens if $K \subset L$ is an arbitrary extension of fields and $l \in L$ is transcendental over $K$.

Comment: The ideal $(p_{_l})$, and I seem to remember that this is exactly how quotients can be seen as coequalizers; I’ll look at my old category theory text for the details, much appreciated. If $l$ is transcendental the kernel is trivial, correct?

Comment: @AlecRhea Right track for quotients and coequalizers. Correct about the transcendental case; moreover, the embedding of integral domains induces a ring homomorphism $\operatorname{Frac}(F[X]) \to K(l) = \operatorname{Frac}(K(l))$.